# Python C++ api: How to access public class attribute?

Tags: c++, python-c-api

I have a C++ class Box that I want to wrap up using python C++ api.

The class is defined as:

```
class Box {
   public:
      int id;   

      Box(double l, double b, double h);

      double getVolume(void); 

      void setLength( double len );

   private:
      double length;      // Length of a box
      double breadth;     // Breadth of a box
      double height;      // Height of a box
};
```

In the C-API I have the following declaration of PyBox:

```
typedef struct 
{
    PyObject_HEAD
    Box *bx;
} PyBox;
```

and the following members table:

```
static PyMemberDef pyBox_members[] = {
    {"id", T_INT, offsetof(PyBox, bx->id), 0, "Box id"},
    {NULL}  /* Sentinel */
};
```

However, when I try to compile the module I get the following error message:

```
error: cannot apply ‘offsetof’ to a non constant address
     {"id", T_INT, offsetof(PyBox, bx->id), 0, "Box id"},
                   ^~~~~~~~
```

How do I specify the correct **offsetof** so that the member **id** corresponds to the public attribute **bx->id**?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The basic issue is that `bx` is a pointer, so `bx->id` could literally anywhere in memory relative to `PyBox`. Therefore `offsetof` can never work and thus defining the members in `PyMemberDef` also can never work.

One solution would be to change the class definition so `Box` is part of the class (and so an offset is meaningful). This may or may not make sense depending on your C++ code:

```
typedef struct 
{
    PyObject_HEAD
    Box *bx;
} PyBox;
```

The better solution would be to use [`PyGetSetDef` instead](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/structures.html#c.PyGetSetDef) to define property getters and setters for `bx->id`.

Comment: Thanks! But how do I use the  PyGetSetDef without defining PyMemberDef? The official docs do not contain that case AFAIK https://docs.python.org/3.5/extending/newtypes.html.

Comment: If you don't need it you just set `tp_members` to 0.

Comment: Thinking about it... if the attribute is public why do we need a getter/setter?

Comment: Because the getter/setter is the C++ <-> Python translation layer. Even when you use `PyMemberDef` then Python automatically generates a getter and setter to convert between `PyObject` and the C++ type. In this case the role of the getter/setter is also to figure out where `bx` is using the pointer.